# Composer network install issue

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile seasiainfotech@0.0.1.bna

when I run the command , I got the below error

✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
Command failed

Comment: I am also facing the same issue while connecting to Oracle Blockchain

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are not able to connect to the fabric network.

Check that you have your PeerAdmin card imported:

`composer card list -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1`

If you do, then try restarting the network with the fabric-tools scripts:

```
./StopFabric.sh
./teardownFabric.sh
```

Start it again by:

```
./startFabric.sh
./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```